# Highcharts format json data from php script / unixtime

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I wrote a php script with target to use  $.getJSON() function.#

The live-temp-data.php create an json file with data like this:[Data](https://steinhagen-wetter.de/highchart/live-temp-data.php)

This is the result : [linechart](https://steinhagen-wetter.de/highchart/index_json.html)

what am I doing wrong ? Code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("live-temp-data.php", function(json) {

            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'steinhagen-wetter.de'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '2020'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature(°C)'
                    }
                },
                time:{
                    timezone: 'Europe/ Berlin'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "datetime",
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        hour: '%H:%M', 
                    },
                },
                series: [{
                     name: 'Outside Temp °C',
                     data:  json
                }]
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>

    </head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open the web console, and you will see the following message :

> https://www.highcharts.com/errors/25/

If you browse this page, you will have the error message :

> **Can't find Moment.js library**
>
> Using the global.timezone option requires the Moment.js library to be
>   loaded.

So import that library, or remove this option, and that problem should be solved.

2) your HTML document is invalid, everything is in the `head` section, you should have a `body` section that contains your graph container.

3) your JSON is not valid : `["[1584713222000, 6.5]","[1584713572000, 6.6]","[1584713989000, 6.7]", ...` 
You should not have quotes around the data items.

Comment: Thanks Joffrey, it works :-)  Result is on the top (link)